# How to run TTP223 Module on AC supply?

Tags: dc, power-modules

My question is about TTP223 module. It is operated on 3-5 Volt DC. But how can I run it on AC supply? I mean I don't want to use DC source. I want to run MOSFET instead of Relay by this.

Comment: How can you power a module that requires DC power without having a DC source? What's wrong with an AC input power source that generates the required 3-5 VDC at its output? Explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: i mean by use of resistor and diode. will it work on pulsating dc power. TTP223 is of 10bucks and to operate i have to use a 2usd power supply.